# NestJs monorepo shared lib injection

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs, monorepo

I have NestJS application with couple microservices stored in single repository (monorepo approach).

`AccessControl` module stores in `libs`, it should be shared across multiple microservices. It has `AccessControlModule.ts` file

```js
@Global()
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'CONNECTION1',
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
        return ClientProxyFactory.create(
          configService.getRMQConnection(),
        );
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    },
    ACGuard,
  ],
  exports: [ACGuard],
  imports: [ConfigModule],
})
export class AccessControlModule implements OnModuleDestroy {
  constructor(
    @Inject('CONNECTION1')
    protected readonly orgConnection: ClientProxy,
  ) {}

  onModuleDestroy(): any {
    this.orgConnection.close();
  }
}
```

This file responsible for module description, it creates connection for another microservice and provide it to `ACGuard` service. `ACGuard.ts`:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ACGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private readonly reflector: Reflector,
    private config: ConfigService,
    @Inject('CONNECTION1')
    private readonly userConnection: ClientProxy;
  ) {}

  public async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
   // do some stuff 
  }
}
```

This part by itself compiles well and logically works fine. Problem begins when I try to inject it into one of microservices. I do it as usual by adding `AccessControlModule` into `import` part of some module. For example `KioskModule`:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ...
    AccessControlModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    KiosksResolver
  ]
})
export class KiosksModule {}
```

Since `AccessControlModule` marked as `Global` and exports `ACGuard` I expect it to be injectable into my providers.

```js
@Resolver('Kiosk')
export class KiosksResolver {
  ...

  @UseGuards(ACGuard)
  @Query()
  kiosks() {
    // ...
  }

   ... 
}
```

But this code falls on the compilation step with error:

> [Nest] 9964   - 05/07/2020, 9:33:02 PM   [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ACGuard (Reflector, ConfigService, ?). Please make sure that the argument CONNECTION1 at index [2] is available in the KiosksModule context.

On the other hand, if i inject it in `KiosksResolver`'s constructor, application builds successfully.

I will appreciate any help and ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way how i solved this issue was exporting `CONNECTION1` provider in `AccessControlModule.ts`.

```js
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'CONNECTION1',
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
        return ClientProxyFactory.create(
          configService.getRMQConnection(),
        );
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    },
    ACGuard,
  ],
  exports: [ACGuard, 'CONNECTION1'],
  imports: [ConfigModule],
})
export class AccessControlModule ...
```

With this export `KioskModule` creates it's own `ACGuard` but provides here connection exported from `AccessControlModule`. 
It's not clear for me why `KioskModule` doesn't get built instance of `ACGuard` exported from `AccessControlModule` but try build it once more.